# Airplane windshield

Tags: modeling, vertices, knife-tool

I’m trying to create a high detail 787 and I am currently on the windshield part.
My question is how do you properly model a knife project object to work on all axis?
Here’s my current window cutout:

[image]

But in real life, the window is farther back.
Here are the windshield blueprints:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Q:** How can I move my current one so it still looks fine, and no weird geometry OR how can I model the knife project object to work on all axis?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a separate plane object, and use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the plane body as the target. You're then going to have to deal with the boolean operator if you want transparency in the window.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, wouldn't use the knife tool on this. I'd create new shapes that correctly trace the outline of the windows on the Z axis, then use them to cut holes in the fuselage with the Boolean operator. I know it's a little more effort but in my opinion you are going to get a much more accurate shape.